# Authenticate method parameters using Spring-Security

Tags: spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 3.1.4.

I have a UsersManager class as follow:

```java
public class UsersManager {

@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public void update(User user){
    ....
            ....
}
}

public class User{
    Integer id;
    String name;
    Integer departmentId;

}
```

The requirement as follow:
A user is allowed to update only users from his department.
Taking in account that the User relies in the secured session, is there a way to do it with Spring Security?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` and add to it `departmentId` property. Then ensure that this object is used by Spring Security as principal (provide your UserDetailsService, set departmentId at the moment of login). Then you can do:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and #principal.departmentId==#user.departmentId")
public void update(User user){
```